# Determining the serialized size of a .NET type and unmanaged memory efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, pointers, unmanaged

My question is whether it is possible to determine the serialized size (in bytes) of a reference type.

Heres the situation:

I am using the BinaryFormatter class to serialize basic .NET types, ie for instance:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }
    public string Foo2 { get; set; } 
}
```

I am serializing each item to a byte[], then adding that segment to the end of an existing byte[] and additionally adding a carriage return at the end of each segment to delimit the objects.

In order to deserialize I use Marshal.ReadByte() as follows:

```
List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();

for (int i = 0; i < MapSize; i++)
{
    byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(readPtr , i); 

    if (b != delim)  // read until encounter a carriage return 
        buffer.Add(b);
    else
        break;
}

readPtr = readPtr + buffer.Count + 1; // incrementing the pointer for the next object

return buffer.ToArray();
```

I believe that using Marshal.Copy() would be more efficient but I need to know the length of the serialized byte segment in advance. Is there a way I can reliably compute this from the type thats being serialized, or an overall more efficient method I can use?

Also, the use of a carriage return won't be reliable, ultimately. So I am wondering if there is a more standard way to delimit the objects, either through customizing my BinaryFormatter or using some other standardized best practice? For instance is there a specific way that the BinaryFormatter delimits objects if its serializing say, a generic List<>?

Comment: This is dangerous; what if a byte with value 13 appears in the serialized data itself? IMO you should **prefix** the length using something like fixed-length (usually 4 or 8 byte) network-byte-order encoding, or "varint" encoding if you are feeling exotic

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks..I am using the carriage return as a temporary solution. The idea of prefixing the length is good, I'll use that, I think.

Comment: There isn't really any need to do length delimiting at all. The BinaryFormatter knows when it has deserialized a complete enclosure.

Comment: @Kennet Belenky, True but this is part of a more complex solution involving shared memory. I want to create a generic list that can be shared between processes and has safe (locked by Mutex) adding and reading operations. If I serialize the entire list everytime one process adds an item, then writing several items to the list in a loop will be very slow, although you are right that reading would be faster.

Comment: @Sean Thoman, Ok, that scenario rules out my idea for putting all the objects in one array before serialization. However, you still don't need delimiters or length prefixes. Use an UnmanagedMemoryStream, and let the issue of pointer advancement be handled by the formatter.

Comment: @Kennet Belenky, Not sure I understand how that would work can you elaborate? Are you referring to a way of serializing each item individually as its added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a terribly good way to determine the serialized length beforehand. The specification for the BinaryFormatter protocol is available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844(v=prot.10).aspx

I'll save you the trouble of reading it for your purposes:

1. It's built to be an extensible format. This allows you to add fields later and still maintain some compatibility with earlier implementations. For your purposes, this means that the length of the serialized form is not fixed in time.
2. It's extremely fragile. The binary format actually encodes the names of the fields in it. If you ever rename a field, the length of the serialized form will change.
3. The binary format actually encompasses a many-to-one relationship between serialized encodings and object data. The same object could potentially be encoded in a number of different ways, with a number of different byte counts for the output (I won't get into why it's written that way).

If you want an easy way to do things, just create an array that contains all the objects and serialize that single array. This solves most of your problems. All the issues of delimiting the different objects are handled by the BinaryFormatter. You won't have excessive memory copying. The final output will be more compact because the BinaryFormatter only has to specify the field names once per invocation.

Finally, I can tell you that the extra memory copy is not the main source of inefficiency in your current implementation. You're getting far more inefficiency from the BinaryFormatter's use of reflection, and the fact that it encodes the field names in the serialized output.

If efficiency is paramount, then I would suggest writing some custom code that encodes the contents of your structures in "plain old data" format. Then you'll have control over how much gets written and how.

Comment: Thanks -- Do you know of any existing 'plain old data' formatters I can grab to save the time of having to reinvent the wheel? I think eventually I will roll my own, perhaps, but for the time being I am just doing a proof-of-concept.

Comment: I re-wrote one of the paragraphs, "If you want an easy way..." That should give you a better way of doing things. As for POD formatters, they tend to be one-offs. Check out Google's Protocol Buffers as an option, but they come with their own set of pros and cons.

Answer (score 4):

Using a byte as delimiter for binary serialized data is awful idea - 13 is perfectly valid value that can be part of serialized data, not just your "delimiter".

Prefix each block with size in bytes instead and read it in blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Marshal.SizeOf to get a struct's native size. This only works for structs and I advise you to set the StructLayout attribute.

I'll pull up some information from the comments because it is surprising yet important:

The CLR has metadata facilities for making the native layout of a struct or class fixed. In C#  this is only possible for structs. But classes can be used that way too.

You can bit-blit a managed type into bytes iff you specify SequentialLayout. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx This facility is not well known but it exists, is specified and supported. Quote: "The class layout attributes (AutoLayout, SequentialLayout and ExplicitLayout) define how the fields of the class instance are laid out **in memory**."

Look at the System.Reflection.TypeAttributes enum. It defines other CLR-level attributes as well. C# does not give access to them but ilasm.exe does.

Comment: I imagine that a reference type can't have a 'native size' (once serialized, anyway), right? This is what I am not sure of.

Comment: The CLR has metadata facilities for making the native layout of a struct or class fixed. In C# I think this is only possible for structs. But classes can be used that way too.

Comment: The in-memory size of an object has nothing to do with its size when serialized by the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: It has, if you tell the CLR to do so. You can bit-blit a managed type into bytes iff you specify SequentialLayout. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx This facility is not well known but it exists, is specified and supported. Quote: "The class layout attributes (AutoLayout, SequentialLayout and ExplicitLayout) define how the fields of the class instance are laid out **in memory**."

Comment: Look at the System.Reflection.TypeAttributes enum. It defines other CLR-level attributes as well. C# does not give access to them but ilasm.exe does.

Comment: @usr Is it specified anywhere that the BinaryFormatter writes binary data to the serialization stream using the same layout that objects have in memory?

Comment: @phoog, the opposite is true. BinaryFormatter is never using the in-memory layout. It is using reflection-only access methods.

Comment: @usr then how does in-memory size of an object have anything to do with its size when serialized by the BinaryFormatter?

Answer (score 1):

I could find the cause of not serializing at all using this code from https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238927-object-size-memory

```
var m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
var b = new
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
b.Serialize(m, Obj);
var size = Convert.ToDouble(m.Length);
```