# C# serialize to same size byte arrays

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the following class:

```
class LabelContainer
{
    public char[] Label = new char[50];
    public char[] Description = new char[100];
    public char[] ArraySize = new char[10];
    public int Offset = 0;
    public byte Dimension = 0;
    public byte DataType = 0;

}
```

I would like to store the content of the class into a file as bytes.  Since Unicode is 2 bytes, the following class should take up 326 bytes for each record in a file.

I want to store the records like this:

| First Record 326 bytes  || Second Record 326 bytes || Third Record 326 bytes  || Forth Record 326 bytes  |

Note that a char buffer such as LabelContainer.Label may be less than 50 characters full.

I would also like to read it back into the class from the file.

Comment: There are tools like the BinarySerializer that helps you do this.  Come back when you run into a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148391/determining-the-serialized-size-of-a-net-type-and-unmanaged-memory-efficiency

Comment: You could check the [fixed sized buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx)